# Restore MySQL database by API R1Soft CDP

Tags: python, mysql, api, r1soft

I'm creating interface to restore backup from R1Soft Backup Manager to my software.
I found function for shedule MySQL restore task in API documentation.

Here is function:

```
UUID com.r1soft.backup.server.apiV2.recoverypoints.RecoveryPointsService.scheduleSimpleMySQLRestore(@WebParam(name="diskSafeId") UUID diskSafeId,@WebParam(name="recoveryPointId") Long recoveryPointId,@WebParam(name="instanceId") Long instanceId,@WebParam(name="restoreInfo") MySQLDatabaseRestore restoreInfo)
```

Everything is clear despite the **MySQLDatabaseRestore** object..
There is no information about this class in documentation.

Somebody has example of code that works with this function? Or maybe somebody has information about **MySQLDatabaseRestore**?

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is not documented but I managed to get this to work with the MySQLDatabaseRestore object having the following properties:

encryptionPassphrase (string) 
databaseNames (string list)